# hide element for medium and up devices bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to hide an element for medium devices and upwards. According to the [bootstrap docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/) i just need to add the class `hidden-md-up` to the element in question. This ism't working though.

Please see demo below. I have added the class `hidden-xs-up` even though i need `hidden-md-up` because it's easier to test within the jsfiddle viewport.

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/21979/

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="hidden-md-up" />
```

Comment: You just need to use `class="hidden-md"` for viewports that fit into the "medium" size category

Comment: Your "bootstrap docs" link references v4-alpha, yet your JSFiddle is using v3. Which version are referencing in your site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're nearly there!

You just need to use `class="hidden-md"` for viewports that fit into the "medium" size category.

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="hidden-md hidden-lg" />
```

Likewise `hidden-xs` for extra small, `hidden-sm` for small, `hidden-lg` for large and so on and so forth.

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**
Just for clarity - the `hidden-md-up` classes are *only* available in (currently) Bootstrap v4-alpha.

The OP was referencing v3, where these classes are not yet available; thus requiring setting all the necessary classes to hide on - I've reflected this in the answer.

Comment: But this only hides for medium devices, not medium and upwards. Bootstrap do have a class `hidden-md-up` as per the link in my question, but i can't get it to work. I'll use the solution you propose and add all the sizes i need to apply it to if i can't find the reason why `hidden-md-up` isn't working.

Comment: In that case, can you clarify which version of bootstrap you are referencing in your site? The doc link you posted is a reference for v4-alpha and your JSFiddle link references v3...

Comment: Ahh that will be why. I'm using version 3, which doesn't have the classes i'm referring to. Thanks. I'll use your solution. Will mark as correct when it allows me.

Comment: There is no `hidden-xl` in Bootstrap 3

Comment: Good point, thanks - got discombobulated between the two, haha! Updated :)

Answer (score 5):

`hidden-*` classes are removed from Bootstrap 4 beta onwards.

If you want to show on medium and up use the d-* classes

eg:

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block">This will show in medium and up</div>
```

If you want to show only in small and below use this

```
   <div class="d-block d-md-none"> This will show only in below medium form factors</div>
```

**Screen size and class chart**

```
| Screen Size        | Class                          |
|--------------------|--------------------------------|
| Hidden on all      | .d-none                        |
| Hidden only on xs  | .d-none .d-sm-block            |
| Hidden only on sm  | .d-sm-none .d-md-block         |
| Hidden only on md  | .d-md-none .d-lg-block         |
| Hidden only on lg  | .d-lg-none .d-xl-block         |
| Hidden only on xl  | .d-xl-none                     |
| Visible on all     | .d-block                       |
| Visible only on xs | .d-block .d-sm-none            |
| Visible only on sm | .d-none .d-sm-block .d-md-none |
| Visible only on md | .d-none .d-md-block .d-lg-none |
| Visible only on lg | .d-none .d-lg-block .d-xl-none |
| Visible only on xl | .d-none .d-xl-block            |
```

> Rather than using explicit .visible-* classes, you make an element
>   visible by simply not hiding it at that screen size. You can combine
>   one .d-*-none class with one .d-*-block class to show an element only
>   on a given interval of screen sizes (e.g. .d-none.d-md-block.d-xl-none
>   shows the element only on medium and large devices).

Documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#responsive-utilities)

Comment: This looks like the way to go nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

The `hidden-md-up` class is only available in Bootstrap 4 so it won't work in your fiddle. Here's a Bootstrap 4 example:

http://www.codeply.com/go/baF57xPjuv

For [Bootstrap 3.x](http://www.codeply.com/go/A0fRlAe9mN) you'd need to use both the `hidden-md` and `hidden-lg` classes:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="hidden-md hidden-lg" />
```